# How to read そう in front of pronouns, nouns, and verbs?

Tags: adverbs, suffixes, demonstratives

I know そう definitions include "so, like that, such, and in such a way," and it can act demonstrative before verbs to describe whatever the verb is happening "like that."

I've seen some Japanese songs with lyrics that have そう in front of nouns and pronouns, but no online dictionaries I've looked up have examples of そう used this way.

Here are some examples:

- 伝わるのは一つだけそう冷めた頬に手のひらで 触れて感じる
- 予感の声聞くよりもそう笑みをかわし手のひらを重ね信じる
- 支えるのはそうあなたが教えてくれたすべて

Answer (score 2):

This そう basically means 'yes' and is a bit of a common filler lyric

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86/ - definition 2, entry 1 under 然う - 'Used to express affirmation or agreement to the interlocutor's words'

Comment: So, you can just ignore it in that form when translating?

Comment: @A.T.Anderson You can ignore it, but you can also add "..., yes, ..." or "yeah" in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: How does one interpret 地図の中描く空 そう今はそれが楽なの? Does そう and the space before it mark a new sentence?